# 2013 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Science Fiction & Fantasy's [second moderator election](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the two new moderators are:

[image: Pureferret] [image: Kevin]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/947007/0).

Also join me in thanking veteran moderator [Gilles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/56) for his service [as he steps down after two years](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2685/2013-community-moderator-election/2690#2690). Gilles was first [appointed as a Moderator Pro Tempore](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/373/moderator-pro-tem-announcement), and did such a great job that y'all elected him a year later when the site launched. Please wish him all the best as he takes that long walk into the cursed earth.

Comment: ... and now we await the inevitable worldwide ferret invasion against mankind. Brace yourselves.

Answer (score 18):

As a *defeated* moderator candidate, I would like to personally congratulate Pureferret and Kevin for their election. I'm sure they will be great moderators that will act for the greater good of scifi.stackexchange.

I would also want to thank the others *defeated* candidates. There was far more quality candidates on this election than positions to fulfill. And I want to thank those who voted for me for the trust you put in my candidature.

Finally, thanks To Gilles. You made a incredible job as a moderator and the good thing is that you cannot resign as a user. I sincerely hope you will stick around.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't expect to win, although I know I'd have been a good moderator, my low reputation and my relative lurker status were bound to show up.  Congratulations to the winners!