# How can I find out who all the current moderators on the site are?

Tags: discussion, support, election, moderators

So, I tried to ping the mods on chat to make sure they are OK with a post of mine.

Just to make sure my brain isn't stuck in 2012, I decided to double check who current mods are.

And discovered that it doesn't appear to be easily discoverable (at least to me)

- We can [tell who the newly elected moderators in 2013 were](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/2013-community-moderator-election-results).
- But, we also need to add in whoever moderators from previous years were (more Meta posts?)
- ... and remove whoever resigned from moderation (in this specific case, we were lucky and the same 2013 post stated who did).

Is there a way to just look up a list of all current site's moderators, ideally usable for any SE site. Preferable NOT involving

- digging through 5+ meta posts
- digging through top user lists and looking which of them has a diamond in a name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We used to be listed on an 'about this site' type of page, but they moved us under the Users tab a year or two ago:

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators